# How to simulate the browser load in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

We need to test our web application with 100+ users with JMeter tool.
Should we use JMeter webdriver plugin to launch the real browsers or can we use the blazemeter plugin to generate the script and run in JMeter? Will the script created with blazemeter simulate the real browser load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theoretically** you can use real browsers, but be aware that browsers are **very** resource intensive so my expectation is that you will need at least one [CPU core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) and at 1 GB of [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) **per browser instance** in order to have enough resources.

This means you will have to go for [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) and on average you will have one slave per 5 browsers. If this is something you can afford - go for it. If don't - be aware that you can [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), to wit:

- Tell JMeter to `Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files` and `Use concurrent pool` of 6 threads. This can be done using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults), the settings live under "Advanced" tab
- Add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to simulate browser cache
- Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to mimic browser cookies
- Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send browser-like headers (i.e. [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding), etc.)
- If your application uses AJAX requests - put the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)